# Call method, when activity unbinds service

Tags: android, android-service

How to call method of my `Service` each time `Activity` unbinds it? It's desirable to don't call it from `ServiceConnection`.

What I want to achieve:

I'm using started service, that checks socket's `InputStream` every second. I want to change this interval to, for example, 1 minute, when application is stoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to call method of my Service each time Activity unbinds it?

Call a method on your `Binder` before calling `unbindService()`.